# Calculating proportions and ignore NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset similar to the following and my end goal is to make a table showing variables like mean salary per gender and the females' mean salary as a proportion of men's.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(Department = c("Dep1", "Dep1","Dep2", "Dep2","Dep3"),
            Gender = c("F", "M",  "F", "M", "F"),
            Salary = seq(10,14))

      Department Gender Salary
1       Dep1      F     10
2       Dep1      M     11
3       Dep2      F     12
4       Dep2      M     13
5       Dep3      F     14
```

Step 1: First I calculate the needed summary statistics using summarise.

```
Table <- x %>% group_by(Department, Gender) %>% summarise(Count = n(),
                                                      AverageSalary = mean(Salary, na.rm = T),
                                                      MedianSalary = median(Salary, na.rm = T))
```

Step 2: To calculate the proportion and add the new columns to "Table" I use a tip I got from this forum a few days ago.

```
Table %>% group_by(Department) %>% 
mutate(`AvgSalaryWomen/Men` = AverageSalary[Gender == "F"]/AverageSalary[Gender == "M"],
     `MedianSalaryWomen/Men` = MedianSalary[Gender == "F"]/MedianSalary[Gender == "M"])
```

My challenge is that Dep3 doesn't have any males and so I get the following error message:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Column `AvgSalaryWomen/Men` must be length 1 (the group size), not 0
```

What I was hoping for was something like this

```
  Department Gender Count AverageSalary MedianSalary AvgSalaryWomen.Men MedianSalaryWomen.Men
1       Dep1      F     1            10           10          0.9090909             0.9090909
2       Dep1      M     1            11           11          0.9090909             0.9090909
3       Dep2      F     1            12           12          0.9230769             0.9230769
4       Dep2      M     1            13           13          0.9230769             0.9230769
5       Dep3      F     1            14           14                 NA                    NA
```

or this

```
  Department Gender Count AverageSalary MedianSalary AvgSalaryWomen.Men MedianSalaryWomen.Men
1       Dep1      F     1            10           10          0.9090909             0.9090909
2       Dep1      M     1            11           11                 NA                    NA
3       Dep2      F     1            12           12          0.9230769             0.9230769
4       Dep2      M     1            13           13                 NA                    NA
5       Dep3      F     1            14           14                 NA                    NA
```

Is there an easy way to obtain either of these two results? I'm guessing that alternative 1 would be the easiest.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ifelse`, you can check if both genders exist in a department before computing the ratios (and if not, returning `NA`). Something like this:

```
Table %>% group_by(Department) %>% 
  mutate(`AvgSalaryWomen/Men` = ifelse(length(unique(Gender)) == 2,
         AverageSalary[Gender == "F"]/AverageSalary[Gender == "M"], NA),
         `MedianSalaryWomen/Men` = ifelse(length(unique(Gender)) == 2, 
          MedianSalary[Gender == "F"]/MedianSalary[Gender == "M"], NA))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 7
> # Groups:   Department [3]
>   Department Gender Count AverageSalary MedianSalary `AvgSalaryWomen/Men` `MedianSalaryWomen/Men`
>   <fct>      <fct>  <int>         <dbl>        <int>                <dbl>                   <dbl>
> 1 Dep1       F          1          10.0           10                0.909                   0.909
> 2 Dep1       M          1          11.0           11                0.909                   0.909
> 3 Dep2       F          1          12.0           12                0.923                   0.923
> 4 Dep2       M          1          13.0           13                0.923                   0.923
> 5 Dep3       F          1          14.0           14               NA                      NA
> ```